# what is the meaning of weighting in mathematics?

Tags: matrices, vectors, weighted-least-squares

What is the mathematical meaning of weighted by a Gaussian for numbers or vectors or Weighting by bilinear and weighted vectors?
Regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: "Weighting" can be thought of as a mathematical model for very concrete physical phenomena such as modeling variable (and not uniform) density within a substance, modeling the variable mass (and therefore the variable weight) of an object, modeling the variable pressure exerted on a surface, modeling the temperature throughout some mass, and many, many more things. If you don't like physical interpretations, "weighting" can be thought of as extra generality with useful applications.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you're interested in computing some stuff about data. However, you don't think that each data point should be counted the same. You can *weigh* the data by giving more value/strength/weight/whatever you wanna call it to some data points than others. The "weight" of a particular data point is how much it counts comparatively to the other points.

This is used in everything from statistics to analysis to combinatorics.

Comment: thanks Stella for your quick reply 
I would be more grateful if you explain by small numerical example if it possible, i understand but not well.